# Erratic behaviour in Visual C++ 2008?

Tags: visual-c++

At first I thought I was going mad, but now I know I'm not. I've only been using Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition for a couple of weeks, but I've found that I have had a problem that I just can't get around, but returning to the program the next day I find that the problem has disappeared.

For example, the last time I was using VC++ I couldn't get Build to output an exe file, but today it has no problem.

Has anyone else found this? I like VC++ but I'm only a beginner and I don't know when it's VC++ being stupid and when it's me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had Visual Studio act up before. Usually it just involves the entire application hanging intermittently. Restarting the application usually fixes the problem.

If this does not fix it, you might try examining the build log to see what's going on, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio changes the menu items based on normal development or debug mode.

So you can't build your exe or do some other things while you're debugging. Unfortunately sometimes you simply forgot that you still have a debug session open somewhere.

Pressing Shift-F5 fixes this.